# reactjs cannot recognize html tags when the tag is appended in the text

Tags: reactjs

I am new tor react and I trying to find the best way for the following scenario:

I have a big chunk of text and I need to first split it to paragraph level and wrap each paragraph in span and then put the whole result in a span.

Here is my code which is working now:

```
/**
* Created by hminaee on 12/26/2016.
 */
import  React from "react";
require("../../../../css/story/body/story-body.css");
require("../../../../css/common/common.css");
export class StoryBodyText extends  React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super();
}
componentWillMount(){
}
componentDidMount(){

}

/**
 *
 * @param text
 * @returns {string}
 */
paragraphGenerator(text){
    var paragraphs=text.split(/\n/g) ;
    return paragraphs;
}


render() {
    return (
        <div className="col-xs-12">
            <div className="col-xs-1"></div>
            <div className="col-xs-10 txt-align-left body-text">{this.paragraphGenerator(this.props.storyText).map((item,i)=> <span >{item}</span>)}</div>
            <div className="col-xs-1"></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

As you can see I have a work around and I return an array of sentences and then I loop through them and span each sentence. However, what I like to do is something like this:

```
 paragraphGenerator(text){
    //var example = "X Y\nX1 Y1\nX2 Y2. mmmmm";
    var paragraphs=text.split(  /\n/g) ;
    var wrapedText="";
    for(var i=0;i<paragraphs.length;i++){
        wrapedText=wrapedText+"<span>"+paragraphs[i]+"</span>";
    }
    return wrapedText;
}
```

So here I create the text with span and instead of looping through an array I would like to do this:

```
<div className="col-xs-10 txt-align-left body-text">{this.paragraphGenerator(this.props.storyText)}</div>
```

But this does not work and instead of having a text wrapped with span I see a text like this when I open browser:

```
<span>some text</span>
```

So the span is not recognized as an html tag. Now my question is , is there any way to do this via the second approach?

Comment: your wrappedText variable is a string. this is exactly what React sees. What you did in your actual example is correct. Why don't you do the same thing in your function?

/// returns an array of <spans>
paragraphGenerator(text) {
    var paragraphs=text.split(/\n/g);
return paragraphs.map(item => <span>{item}</span>);
}

Comment: @DOMZE thanx for answering yes you are right in this case it works but I have a very complicated text manipulation and handling that without using the second method is very troublesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the react property `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` like so:

```
<div className="col-xs-10 txt-align-left body-text" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.paragraphGenerator(this.props.storyText)}></div>
```

Link to documentation: [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)